# SQL Logic doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have character data stored in a column that was imported from a data file. The character data represents an integer value, but.. the last (rightmost) character isn't always a digit character. I'm attempting to convert the character data into the integer value using a SQL expression, but it's not working.

My attempt at a SQL statement is shown below, and a test case that demonstrates it's not working. My approach is to split off the rightmost character from the string, do the appropriate conversion, and then string it back together and cast to integer.

**Q:** How can I fix my SQL expression to convert this correctly, or what SQL expression can be used to do the conversion?

**DETAILS**

The rightmost character in the string can be one of the values in the "Code" column below. The "Digit" column shows that actual integer value represented by the character, and the "Sign" column shows whether the overall string is to be interpreted as a negative value, or a positive value.

For example, the string value `'023N'` represents an integer value of `+235`. (The rightmost 'N' character represents a digit value of 5, with a positive sign). The string value of `'104}'` represents an integer value of `-1040`. (The rightmost `'}'` charcacter represents a digit value of '0' and makes the overall integer value negative.)

Here's the table that shows the required conversion.

```
Code  Digit  Sign
 '}'   '0'    -
 'J'   '1'    -
 'K'   '2'    -
 'L'   '3'    -
 'M'   '4'    -
 'N'   '5'    -
 'O'   '6'    -
 'P'   '7'    -
 'Q'   '8'    -
 'R'   '9'    -
 '{'   '0'    +
 'A'   '1'    +
 'B'   '2'    +
 'C'   '3'    +
 'D'   '4'    +
 'E'   '5'    +
 'F'   '6'    +
 'G'   '7'    +
 'H'   '8'    +
 'I'   '9'    +
```

Here's a table of example values:

```
 Create Table #Punch
 (
 aa varchar(20)
 )

Insert Into #Punch values ('046')
Insert into #Punch values ('027')
Insert into #Punch values ('004')
Insert into #Punch values ('020')
Insert into #Punch values ('090')
```

And this is the SQL statement do do the conversion, but it's not working correctly for character strings that have just regular digit characters. (The sample table above are examples of other character strings that should be converted to integer value.

This SQL statement is returning an integer value of `184` for the character string `046`, when I expect it to return `46`.

**Q:** Why is my SQL statement returning an integer value of `184` instead of `46` for the character string `'046'`?

```
      select
      aa, Answervalue =
      (cast(
     substring(aa, 1, len(aa)-1) +
     case
        when right(aa,1) in ('{','}','0') then '0'         
        when right(aa,1) between 'A' and 'I' then cast(ascii(right(aa,1))-64 as char(1))
        when right(aa,1) between 'J' and 'R' then cast(ascii(right(aa,1))-73 as char(1))
        else ''
     end
    as int) *
  case
     when right(aa,1) in ('{','0') or right(aa,1) between 'A' and 'I' then 1
     when right(aa,1) in ('}') or right(aa,1) between 'J' and 'R' then -1
     when aa in (aa) then aa
   end)
 from
 (
select aa from #Punch
 ) bb
```

---

For given inserted value, the result of "046" is coming as "184". It should be "46". For "004" the result is coming as "0". It should be "4". Other than these issue, logic works fine. If the column value aa is numeric, and there is no code\characters (for example {,A,N,B, etc) in the value, I want to put as original value. so if it is 046 then value should be 46.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You need to describe your logic, just because what your code does not produce results you expected, we can't guess what logic part of code fails

Comment: For given inserted value, the result of "046" is coming as "184". It should be "46". For "004" the result is coming as "0". It should be "4".

Comment: Why? you just said what you expect but now how you get there.

Comment: A signed overpunch is a code used to store the sign of a number by changing the last digit.  Code value in the right most character is replaced with Digit given. For example 10} is going to be (-100)
45A is going to be (451). 03} is going to be Negative 30 (-30). Hope that make sense.

Comment: It was pretty clear what OP was asking; but I have made some significant edits to the question to make it more clear. Some answers given to the question before it was closed explain exactly where the problem is, and give an alternative SQL expression that meets the OP specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't edit my original (I missed your point about the numeric) so here it is again:

It looks to me like you inserted the wrong data into your table.

Try:

```
Insert Into #Punch values ('04O')
Insert into #Punch values ('02P')
Insert into #Punch values ('00D')
Insert into #Punch values ('02{')
Insert into #Punch values ('09}')
```

As far as checking to see if the value is numeric, that's another issue.  Try using:

```
      select
      aa, Answervalue = CASE WHEN IsNumeric(aa) = 1 THEN aa ELSE
      (cast(
     substring(aa, 1, len(aa)-1) +
     case
        when right(aa,1) in ('{','}','0') then '0'         
        when right(aa,1) between 'A' and 'I' then cast(ascii(right(aa,1))-64 as char(1))
        when right(aa,1) between 'J' and 'R' then cast(ascii(right(aa,1))-73 as char(1))
        else ''
     end
    as int) *
  case
     when right(aa,1) in ('{','0') or right(aa,1) between 'A' and 'I' then 1
     when right(aa,1) in ('}') or right(aa,1) between 'J' and 'R' then -1
     when aa in (aa) then aa
   end) END
 from
 (
select aa from #Punch
 ) bb
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your problems is this line:

```
when aa in (aa) then aa
```

With a value of `'046'`, the leftmost two characters are `'04'`, multiply that by `'046'` and you get integer value 184.

I would do the test of that rightmost character one time, with just one `CASE` expression, rather than checking the same thing in multiple CASE expressions and doing the multiplication.

The original statement is just too much work to figure out what it's doing, with the multiple CASE expressions and the multiplication and the CAST.

Using a single CASE expression makes for a much more straightforward SQL statement; by getting the return expression as a single expression, that's much easier to decipher, even if it means repeating a bit of similar code.

For SQL Server, a somewhat lengthier expression would be MUCH easier to decipher, and would make it much easier for the reader to understand what the expression is doing:

```
 SELECT aa
      , Answervalue =
        CASE RIGHT(aa,1)
        WHEN '{' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'0') AS INT)
        WHEN 'A' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'1') AS INT)
        WHEN 'B' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'2') AS INT)
        WHEN 'C' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'3') AS INT)
        WHEN 'D' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'4') AS INT)
        WHEN 'E' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'5') AS INT)
        WHEN 'F' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'6') AS INT)
        WHEN 'G' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'7') AS INT)
        WHEN 'H' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'8') AS INT)
        WHEN 'I' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'9') AS INT)
        WHEN '}' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'0') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'J' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'1') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'K' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'2') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'L' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'3') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'M' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'4') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'N' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'5') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'O' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'6') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'P' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'7') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'Q' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'8') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN 'R' THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'9') AS INT) * -1
        ELSE CAST(aa AS INT) 
        END
   FROM Punch#
```

Or, you could do something like this:

```
 SELECT aa
      , Answervalue =
        CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(aa,1) IN ('{')
           THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'0') AS INT)
        WHEN RIGHT(aa,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'I'
           THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa,1))-64 AS CHAR(1))) AS INT)
        WHEN RIGHT(aa,1) IN ('}')
           THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),'0') AS INT) * -1
        WHEN RIGHT(aa,1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R'
           THEN CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(aa,LEN(aa)-1),CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa,1))-73 AS CHAR(1))) AS INT * -1
        ELSE
           CAST(aa AS INT)
        END
   FROM Punch#
```

For MySQL, that would look something like this:

```
 SELECT aa
      , CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(aa,1) IN ('{')
           THEN CONCAT(LEFT(aa,CHAR_LENGTH(aa)-1),'0') + 0
        WHEN RIGHT(aa,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'I'
           THEN CONCAT(LEFT(aa,CHAR_LENGTH(aa)-1),CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa,1))-64 AS CHAR(1))) + 0
        WHEN RIGHT(aa,1) IN ('}')
           THEN CONCAT(LEFT(aa,CHAR_LENGTH(aa)-1),'0') * -1 + 0
        WHEN RIGHT(aa,1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R'
           THEN CONCAT(LEFT(aa,CHAR_LENGTH(aa)-1),CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa,1))-73 AS CHAR(1))) * -1 + 0
        ELSE aa + 0
        END AS Answervalue
   FROM Punch#
```

**NOTE:** In MySQL, we can replace the `CAST( x AS INT)` with either `CAST( x AS SIGNED)`, or we can do an addition operation to cause an implicit conversion to numeric.

---

I'm not entirely comfortable subtracting 64 or 73 from the ASCII value. (Because I haven't tested that to ensure that works with all character sets.)

I'd actually be tempted to setup a lookup table, and use an outer join operation. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE _convert_zoned_decimal
( `zdigit` CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, `rdigit` CHAR(1) NOT NULL
, `rsign`  TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO _convert_zoned_decimal VALUES
 ('}','0',-1),('J','1',-1),('K','2',-1),('L','3',-1),('M','4',-1)
,('N','5',-1),('O','6',-1),('P','7',-1),('Q','8',-1),('R','9',-1)
,('{','0',+1),('A','1',+1),('B','2',+1),('C','3',+1),('D','4',+1)
,('E','5',+1),('F','6',+1),('G','7',+1),('H','8',+1),('I','9',+1)
;
```

With that table, I could use an outer join operation and do the replacement, something like this for MySQL:

```
 SELECT aa
      , CASE
        WHEN z.zdigit IS NOT NULL
        THEN CONCAT(LEFT(aa,CHAR_LENGTH(aa)-1),z.rdigit) * z.rsign
        ELSE aa + 0
        END AS Answervalue
   FROM Punch# t
   LEFT
   JOIN _convert_zoned_decimal z
     ON z.zdigit = RIGHT(t.aa,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken you query and divided it into the parts to look at it in parts to see what is going on.

```
 SELECT aa
       ,Answervalue = ( CAST(SUBSTRING(aa, 1, LEN(aa) - 1) + CASE WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '{', '}', '0' ) THEN '0'
                                                                  WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'I'
                                                                  THEN CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa, 1)) - 64 AS CHAR(1))
                                                                  WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R'
                                                                  THEN CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa, 1)) - 73 AS CHAR(1))
                                                                  ELSE ''
                                                             END AS INT)
                        * CASE WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '{', '0' )
                                    OR RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'I' THEN 1
                               WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '}' )
                                    OR RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R' THEN -1
                               WHEN aa IN ( aa ) THEN aa
                          END )
       ,PartOne = SUBSTRING(aa, 1, LEN(aa) - 1)
       ,PartTwo = CASE WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '{', '}', '0' ) THEN '0'
                       WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'I' THEN CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa, 1)) - 64 AS CHAR(1))
                       WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R' THEN CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa, 1)) - 73 AS CHAR(1))
                       ELSE ''
                  END
       ,PartThree = CASE WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '{', '0' )
                              OR RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'I' THEN 1
                         WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '}' )
                              OR RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R' THEN -1
                         WHEN aa IN ( aa ) THEN aa
                    END
    FROM (
           SELECT aa
            FROM #Punch
         ) bb
```

the results are as follows

[image]

Logic is `CAST(PartOne + PartTwo as INT)*PartThree`

As you can see the last part of your clause generates same value as what you have in `aa` thus first part gets multiplied by third part that is where you getting `AA='046' =184` as you can see '023' turns to 46 and etc. so any value where all three characters are numeric last 2 digits get multiplied by second digit.

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can modify your code to the following.

```
 SELECT aa
       ,Answervalue = CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(aa AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN aa
                           ELSE ( CAST(SUBSTRING(aa, 1, LEN(aa) - 1)
                                  + CASE WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '{', '}', '0' ) THEN '0'
                                         WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'I'
                                         THEN CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa, 1)) - 64 AS CHAR(1))
                                         WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R'
                                         THEN CAST(ASCII(RIGHT(aa, 1)) - 73 AS CHAR(1))
                                         ELSE ''
                                    END AS INT) * CASE WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '{', '0' )
                                                            OR RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'I' THEN 1
                                                       WHEN RIGHT(aa, 1) IN ( '}' )
                                                            OR RIGHT(aa, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R' THEN -1
                                                       WHEN aa IN ( aa ) THEN aa
                                                  END )
                      END
    FROM #Punch
```

All I added was `CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(aa AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN aa ELSE` before your logic start. This way you avoid doing logic if it is integer which will give you desired results.

Results:

```
AA      AnswerValue
023     23
046     46
027     27
004     4
020     20
090     90
10}     -100
45A     451
03}     -30
```

Answer (score 1):

This code sets up a local table to test the over punch decode Case statement. Fld is the overpunch field and the output is cast as money and divided by 100 as the last 2 digits of the decoded field were pennies (or cents) in our case:

```
Declare @MyTable as table
(
Fld     varchar(20)
)

Insert into @MyTable values ('00056i')

Select Fld from @MyTable

Select
    Case
    when isnull(Fld,'')='' then null
    when len(isnull(Fld,''))=0 then null
    when right(Fld,1)='}' then cast('-' + left(Fld,(len(Fld)-1))+'0' as money)/100
    when (ascii(right(upper(Fld),1))>=74 and ascii(right(upper(Fld),1))<=82) then cast('-' + left(Fld,(len(Fld)-1))+char(ascii(right(upper(Fld),1))-25) as money)/100
    when right(Fld,1)='{' then cast(left(Fld,(len(Fld)-1))+'0' as money)/100
    when (ascii(right(upper(Fld),1))>=65 and ascii(right(upper(Fld),1))<=73) then cast(left(Fld,(len(Fld)-1))+char(ascii(right(upper(Fld),1))-16) as money)/100
    End as FldDecode

    from @MyTable
```